# implicit: how to let implicit value take effect?

Tags: scala

how to let implicit value p2 take effect?

```
def test(f: =>Int=>Int=>Int)={
   f(1)  //it won't use the implicit p2.
}
val p1:Int=1
implicit val p2:Int=2   //here define a implicit value
test{a1=>implicit a2=>a1+a2}  // here define a implicit function, but how to let it use p2 which defined implicitly?
```

I tried to fake an example similar to below call to isAuthenticated, it has the singuature as
isAuthenticated { username => **implicit** request =>  Ok("Hello " + username)}

```
//in a Security trait                                                                    
 def username(request: RequestHeader) = request.session.get("email")                     
 def onUnauthorized(request: RequestHeader) = Results.Redirect(routes.Application.login)
 def isAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = {
   Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
     Action(request => f(user)(request))
   }
}                                                                                       
//then in a controller                                                                   
def index = isAuthenticated { username => implicit request =>
    Ok("Hello " + username)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`test` doesn't (and can't) know that `f`'s second argument is implicit. You can write

```
def test(f: =>Int=>Int=>Int)={
   f(1)(implicitly[Int])
}
```

which requires an implicit `Int` to be in scope (in your case, `p2`).

Also, there seems to be no reason to make the argument to `test` or `isAuthenticated` by-name (i.e. `=>Int=>Int=>Int` instead of `Int=>Int=>Int`), it'll just add overhead.